# How to add third level nav in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

New to ruby on rails, trying to get this url structure:

```
/about
/about/staff
/about/contact
/about/brazil
/about/brazil/staff
/about/brazil/contact
```

When I do:

```
rails generate controller about index
rails generate controller about staff
rails generate controller about contact
```

I set my routes to:

```
get "about", :to => "about#index"
get "about/staff", :to => "about#staff"
get "about/contact", :to => "about#contact"
```

And all is well, but I got stumped when I need to do the same for a third level for the brazil office

Should I just do

```
rails generate controller about brazil_index
rails generate controller about brazil_staff
rails generate controller about brazil_contact

get "about/brazil", :to => "about#brazil_index"
get "about/brazil/staff", :to => "about#brazil_staff"
get "about/brazil/contact", :to => "about#brazil_contact"
```

Or is there a cleaner way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to call this `rails generate controller About index staff contact`

to generate `AboutController` with three actions `index`, `staff` and `contact`. Then you want to allow passing in id parameter as the second path element:

Then in `config/routes.rb`:

```
  get "about/index"
  get "about/staff"
  get "about/contact"
  get "about/:id/index" => 'about#index'
  get "about/:id/staff" => 'about#staff'
  get "about/:id/contact" => 'about#contact'
```

When I check routes with `rake routes` I see now:

```
$ rake routes
  about_index GET /about/index(.:format)       {:controller=>"about", :action=>"index"}
  about_staff GET /about/staff(.:format)       {:controller=>"about", :action=>"staff"}
about_contact GET /about/contact(.:format)     {:controller=>"about", :action=>"contact"}
              GET /about/:id/index(.:format)   {:controller=>"about", :action=>"index"}
              GET /about/:id/staff(.:format)   {:controller=>"about", :action=>"staff"}
              GET /about/:id/contact(.:format) {:controller=>"about", :action=>"contact"}
```

You can now request http://localhost:3000/about/brazil/staff and the value of params[:id] will be "brazil".

Comment: This is good, but I'd recommend using the param name `:country` instead of `:id` like this: `get "about/:country/index"` -- that way you'd access the country value as `params[:country]` instead of `params[:id]`.

Answer (score 1):

One good option for this is to seperate the routes by using a 'namespace' in your `/config/routes.rb` file like this:

```
namespace :about do
  match '/' => 'about#index'
  match '/staff' => 'about#staff'
  match '/contact' => 'about#contact'
  match '/:country/staff' => 'about#staff'
  match '/:country/contact' => 'about#contact'
end
```

If you then run `rake routes`, you can see the routing that results:

```
/about(.:format)                  {:controller=>"about/about", :action=>"index"}
/about/staff(.:format)            {:controller=>"about/about", :action=>"staff"}
/about/contact(.:format)          {:controller=>"about/about", :action=>"contact"}
/about/:country/staff(.:format)   {:controller=>"about/about", :action=>"staff"}
/about/:country/contact(.:format) {:controller=>"about/about", :action=>"contact"}
```

So all these route to the same controller (which I believe is what you wanted), and you have only three actions: `staff`, `index` and `contact`. The `:country` value will be passed in as a parameter if it exists in the url and would be accessed as `params[:country]`.

Is this what you were trying to do?